# Asp.net page loads with weird content in Internet explorer 7 & 7+ versions

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

I am working with asp.net 4.0 application and facing issue with internet explorer.

The functionality of asp.net page to save the data in database simultaneously hook one background process and redirect to next page. We have used "System.Threading.Tasks" for background process to generate the report by replacing bookmarks in RTF template and generate PDF. Report generation process implemented with the help of "Microsoft.Office.Interop" objects. After generation of PDF system saves the PDF stream in SQL server database. The bookmark replacement and PDF generation is long running process that's why we have used background process for it. All the implemented classes for this process kept on application App_code folder.

The problem which we are facing. The destination page which redirected after data save and hooking background process loads with wearied content in internet explorer 7 & 7+ versions. This issue is occurring only in IE browsers and not every time. If user refresh the page the page gets loaded with actual content.

I felt this is a JavaScript and ScriptManager issue so I changed the aspx code as all JavaScript code placed on bottom of the page and set the ScriptMode of script manager to Release but all does not help. Please help me to fix the issue. 
Below is the screen which user got some time. Please help me to fix the issue
[image]

Comment: Please help. If any body need more information I can  post it.

Comment: Can you separate out the problem and give a reproducable link, so that all can verify the same in IE and get back to you with solution. By the way you mean `weird` not `Wearied` ?

Comment: Issue occurs occasionally and specially in IE browser. Reproducible link is not possible to share as it works only with secure VPN connection.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the mimetype of the stream you are returning to the client... 
When the user refreshes that request, the document is read from disk, and mimetype is set ...

something like for MVC.

```
return new FileContentResult(bytes, "application/pdf");
```

for ASP.NET :

http://www.devtoolshed.com/aspnet-download-file-web-browser

Comment: I am not giving pdf download facility to the user on page, we are just writing  the PDF on physical disk then converting in to stream and saving in database.

Comment: page content (image) which I shown on my post is PDF stream?

Comment: It looks like anyhow you are returning some binary data... It could be a PDF or not .... I don't think it's a javascript or scriptmanager issue it should never return such a thing if you don't explicitly returns binary data.

You should better post the main code of your Request :=)

Comment: Yes, I will post the code tomorrow. One thing also surprising me that this issue  occurs occasionally and only in IE browser.